# Replace specific Text in Header, Footer and normal Text in Word file

Tags: powershell, ms-word, header, find, footer

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which replaces one String with another string in word files. I need to update more than 500 word templates and files so I don't want to make it by hand. One problem is that i can't find the text in footer or header, because they are all individual and are tables with images. I manage to find the text in the normal "body" text but haven't replaced it by now. Here is my code for finding.

```
$path = "C:\Users\BambergerSv\Desktop\PS\Vorlagen"
$files = Get-Childitem $path -Include *dotm, *docx, *.dot, *.doc, *.DOT, *DOTM, *.DOCX, *.DOC -Recurse |
         Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) }
$application = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$application.Visible = $true
$findtext = "www.subdomain.domain.com"

function getStringMatch {
    foreach ($file In $files) {
        #Write-Host $file.FullName
        $document = $application.Documents.Open($file.FullName, $false, $true)
        if ($document.Content.Text -match $findtext) {
            Write-Host "found text in file " $file.FullName "`n"
        }
        try {
            $application.Documents.Close()
        } catch {
            continue
            Write-Host $file.FullName "is a read only file" #if it is write protected because of the makros
        }
    }
    $application.Quit()
}

getStringMatch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched on internet.I found an answer to this question.

At first you need to understand VBA. Write the below macro in MS WORD and then save it.

```
Public Function CustomReplace(findValue As String, replaceValue As String) As String

 For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

     myStoryRange.find.Execute FindText:=findValue, Forward:=True, ReplaceWith:=replaceValue, replace:=wdReplaceAll
     While myStoryRange.find.Found
           myStoryRange.find.Execute FindText:=findValue, Forward:=True, ReplaceWith:=replaceValue, replace:=wdReplaceAll
     Wend
     While Not (myStoryRange.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
          Set myStoryRange = myStoryRange.NextStoryRange
          myStoryRange.find.Execute FindText:=findValue, Forward:=True, ReplaceWith:=replaceValue, replace:=wdReplaceAll

          While myStoryRange.find.Found
               myStoryRange.find.Execute FindText:=findValue, Forward:=True,ReplaceWith:=replaceValue, replace:=wdReplaceAll
          Wend

     Wend
  Next myStoryRange
CustomReplace = ActiveDocument.FullName
End Function
```

After the above macro added to MS WORD, go to Powershell and execute the below code.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.visible=$false
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Test" -Filter *.docx

$find=[ref]"Hello"
$replace=[ref]"Hi"


for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
  $filename = $files[$i].FullName 
  $doc = $word.Documents.Open($filename)

  $word.Run("CustomReplace",$find,$replace)
  $doc.Save()
  $doc.close()
  }

 $word.quit()
```